# MySQL: Returning total record count from a CROSS JOINed row?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, cross-join

Here's my SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/672f4/1

I'm trying to get the total count of records for each `name` (technically, their cross-linked `pid`) that exists inside the table `info`. So, for example, the `TOTAL` column should read **3** for **rob**, and **1** for everyone else (jon, tim, and ben). The output should appear as so:

```
PID     NAME    TOTAL
1       rob     3
2       jon     1
3       tim     1
4       ben     1
```

**STRUCTURE:**

```
create table names (
  pid int(10),
  name char(20)
);

insert into names values
    (1, 'rob'),
    (2, 'jon'),
    (3, 'tim'),
    (4, 'ben');

create table info (
  id int(10),
  pid int(10),
  info char(20),
  extra char(10)
);

insert into info values
    (1, 1, 'rob blah', 'heh 1'),
    (2, 2, 'jon blah', 'ha 1'),
    (3, 3, 'tim blah', 'ho 1'),
    (4, 4, 'ben blah', 'hi 1'),
    (5, 1, 'rob blah', 'heh 2'),
    (6, 1, 'rob blah', 'heh 3');
```

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT pid, name, total FROM names CROSS JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(extra) AS total FROM info ) AS total;
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Include all the required data/queries in the question itself. SQLFiddle is nice, but should not required.

Comment: Yes, sir. Updating my post as we speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT names.pid, name, COUNT(extra) as total 
FROM names 
LEFT JOIN info 
ON info.pid=names.pid 
GROUP BY names.pid
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b0b9/10)

Comment: I don't understand any of that right now, but it works, and I'm going to play with it until I do. Thanks for teaching me. One question, if i may: is there a particular reason a LEFT JOIN is superior in this circumstance?

Comment: @daveycroqet please study from here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html or look other references it is easy